# Copy to Clipboard in NodeJs with Express Handlebars template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-handlebars

How we can implement **copy to clipboard** feature on button click in **NodeJs** using **express handlebar** template.

I have tried using Javascript but it's not working.

Below is the code which I have tried:

**myFile.handlebars** :

```
<input type="button" id="linkBtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="copyLink()" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Copy to Clipboard" value="copy link" readonly />

<script>
  function copyLink() {
    let copyText = document.getElementById("linkBtn");
    /* Select the text field */
    copyText.select();
    /* Copy the text inside the text field */
    document.execCommand("copy");

    /* Alert the copied text */
    //alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
  }
</script>
```

[Copy to the clipboard using JS](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trying to copy text from the button. you can select button text. add content which you want to select in any other tag

here is a solution:

```
<input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="copyLink()" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Copy to Clipboard" value="copy link" readonly />

<span id="copyText">Copy this Text</span>

<script>
  function copyLink() {
    let copyText = document.getElementById("copyText") 

    var selection = window.getSelection();

    var range = document.createRange();

    range.selectNodeContents(copyText);

    selection.removeAllRanges();

    selection.addRange(range);

    document.execCommand('copy');
  }
</script>
```

here is a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5mryvpc6/